# How to generate screenshot from the browser and compare it with pdf

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, regression-testing, pdf-file

Currently we manually compare (test) the PDF layout with the website on the browser. However, I'm looking for a tool which could automate the testing process. I've looked into a Visual regression testing library called PhantomCSS. However, it only compares the screenshot taken from the browser (cross-browser) and not against the PDF layout which I'm looking for. Is there any tool available for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can open PDF file in browser , and then use PhantomCSS. It will compare both screenshots of PDF file and Web page taken from the browser.

Try to create PDF from web pages and compare documents using Acrobat 9. ([tutorial](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/a9video_web_capture_and_compare))